# Flat Areas Bake with Blocky Colour Chunks

Tags: texture-baking, artifacts

I don't understand why Blender can't bake a flat area without making random blocks on it. I know it did so before.

This is Blender 2.93, Cycles render:
[image: bake vs flat surfaces]

Red: the top of the base
Blue: the cover of the book
Bottom: the base porcelain texture (note: the book is the same, but does not have a normal map)

[image: texture vs geometry]

This is the texture displayed on the book cover. No, I'm not baking it with a texture; I'm baking the material **to** the texture.

[image: pages of the book with blocks and streaks]

This is the top of the book, the pages. These are gently curved, but still largely flat. There are blocky blobs. Also, what's going on in that one section where there are several gradients?

What I've tried:

- baking this in Blender 3.6.0
- adding subdivision surface to add up to 6 levels of subdivision (something I saw on an answer to a similar question)
- changing the area light size from 1.8m to 18m (something else i saw on another similar question here)
- applying all the modifiers in 'visual geometry to mesh' and baking THAT
- turning off everything else in the scene and only baking the book
- removing doubles. (oh, sorry, 'merge with default tiny distance')
- using only one material per object

UPDATE:  i managed to fix it this morning, but i still don't understand WHY it's fixed.

i shrank the meshes to 1/10th their size, which is the final export size, and also the size of the meshes i had set up the lighting and materials for in a previous iteration of this project.

so i guess it's a mesh size vs light size issue?  but i scaled up the area light 10x... i don't get it.  can someone explain in a real answer?  thank you!